# Stack Level Too Deep, Modules and Classes

Tags: ruby, class, module, stack

I am new to Stackoverflow and I am having some trouble on a coding challenge. I need to be able to output the president's age, name, citizenship, along with a catchphrase. I keep receiving the error,

stack level too deep
exercise.rb:12

Can anyone explain, what is wrong? What does the stack level too deep mean?

module Presidential
      attr_accessor :name, :age, :citizenship

```
  def initialize(name, age)
    @name, @age, @citizenship = name, age, self.class.citizenship
  end
end

class FrancePresident
  include Presidential
  def citizenship 
    "#{self.citizenship}, #{catchphrase}" 
  end 
  def name
    "#{name}, #{catchphrase}"
  end
  def age
    "#{age}, #{catchphrase}"
  end
  def catchphrase 
    "bien sur"
  end
  def self.citizenship
    "La France"
  end
end
```

**Spec:**

```
describe FrancePresident do
  describe "catchphrase" do
    it "sounds just right" do
      expect( FrancePresident.citizenship ).to eq("La France")
      sarcozy = FrancePresident.new("Nicolas Sarkozy", 59)
      expect( sarcozy.citizenship ).to eq("La France, bien sur")
      expect( sarcozy.age ).to eq("59, bien sur")
      expect( sarcozy.name ).to eq("Nicolas Sarkozy, bien sur")
    end
  end

  describe "inheritance" do
    it "should not inherit from President" do
      expect( FrancePresident.superclass.to_s ).not_to eq('President')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Ruby keeps a stack of things waiting for something, and it is getting too large:

```
class FrancePresident
  def citizenship 
    self.citizenship
  end 
end

sarkozy = FrancePresident.new
sarkozy.citizenship
```

When the `citizenship` method is called, Ruby executes it. The execution is: call the `citizenship` method. Ruby does this about 10000 times before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add line numbers to your question, this would make it easier to get the exact line nr. 12 from your error.. but what i can see so far is following:

```
def citizenship 
  "#{self.citizenship}, #{catchphrase}" 
end
```

You are calling the method "citizenship" on your instance method "citizenship"..this will end in an stack level to deep, because you call the same method inside the method itself.. I can see that you have a class method "citizenship". You must edit your instance method citizenship like following:

```
def citizenship
  "#{FrancePresident.citizenship}, #{catchphrase}"
end
```

or

```
def citizenship
  "#{self.class.citizenship}, #{catchphrase}"
end
```

and your instance method "citizenship" will be save. Within the scope of your instance method "citizenship" the "self" is the instance and not the class. Outside of the instance "self" is the class.

if you fix this like I said you will get your next errors on the "name" and "age" instance method...because of the same raison..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, the solution lies in NOT accessing the name and age variables from the Presidential module, but from the FrancePresident class itself.

```
class FrancePresident
  attr_accessor :name, :age
  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
```

Then you call the instance variable @